# How to read multiple lines from csv into a single dataframe row with pandas

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I have a file that has a comment on the first the line, followed by two lines with the names of the headers slippted across them and a third line with the name of the index. The file looks like this:

```
# 3 5 <-- this is a comment indicating how many rows and column are matrix data
head1 head2 head3
head4 head5
idx1 idx2 idx3

1.1 1.2 1.3 
1.4 1.5
2.1 2.2 2.3
2.4 2.5
3.1 3.2 3.3
3.4 3.5
```

How can I read the file with pandas in order to have a dataframe that looks like this?

```
        head1 head2 head3 head4 head5
idx1    1.1   1.2   1.3   1.4   1.5
idx2    2.1   2.2   2.3   2.4   2.5
idx3    3.1   3.2   3.3   3.4   3.5
```

Comment: this is a very custom requirement. I would recommend read the csv in python. Parse as you want. Create a dataframe from the read values.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Taking away the text file structure, is there any option to read two lines into a single row with pandas? In negative case I'll parse it totally on my own and create a DataFrame after.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can specify the `skiprows` keyword of [read_csv](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) in order to create one data frame that contains all 3-value lines (by skipping the 2-valued ones) and then create another data frame which contains all the 2-value lines. Note that you can specify the header row with the `header` keyword.

So you can parse the csv file into two different data frames which you can [concatenate](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html) later on.

As an example (assuming 3-valued lines are even line numbers and 2-valued lines are odd line numbers):

```
df3 = pd.read_csv(..., skiprows=lambda x: x%2 == 1)
df2 = pd.read_csv(..., skiprows=lambda x: x%2 == 0)
```

Then you can use [concat](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html) in order to concatenate the two data frames into a single one:

```
df = pd.concat((df3, df2))
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. The idea is great! I changed the last line with `concat` into `df = pd.concat([df2, df3], axis=1)`

Comment: Also, "filter" is not necessary.  This works just as well since pandas will feed the index into the lambda function: `skiprows=lambda x: x%2==1`